# Why is the alert email for a list truncating the message body?

Tags: email, 2007, alert

I have created one SharePoint Blog site. I have one Blog site collection called MyBlog, which contains a list named "Post".

I clicked on the "Alert me" in list settings, so that I can get alerts emails when any type of change occurs in the list.

With one new post added to the list, I got the alert email, but in the email, the body does not contain the full description of the post, rather it is truncated to some extent.

Could you please tell me, is there any limitations in the number of characters in the Body of the email, while sending email through the Alert me feature in a list?

Answer (score 1):

I think the "Alert Me" feature is to notify a change or addition to the list (and provide a link to the relevant list item), rather than delivery of content. Try RSS if you want content delivered upon addition to the list.